# Looking for tech podcasts in the German language

Tags: podcast

Does anyone know of quality, weekly **tech podcasts** in **German** similar to e.g. Hanselminutes, .NET Rocks, Code Cast, Herding Code, etc.?

Comment: There's http://www.bitsundso.de/ and http://technikwuerze.de/ which are pretty similar to Tech Weekly/Click, pretty decent topics.

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Comment: There is also http://devcouch.de

Answer (score 1):

There is [Omegatau](http://omegataupodcast.net/) on different science and engineering topics.